# Differential of a function in integrals

Tags: calculus

In riemann sums,$dx$ is the $\Delta x$ (which are evenly spaced) when goes to $0$. And by $\int_{0}^{x}dx=x$,we mean the sum of those equally spaced infinitesimals is $x$. But when we use $\int g(f(x)) df(x)$ we treat $f(x)=z$ as an independent variable like $x$ and use the properties we did with $x$,for example $dx$ are evenly spaced infinitesimals but $df(x)$ behave irregularly meaning their differences are not same.Why is it then justified to treat $df(x)$ as an independent variable like $x$ although it is a dependent variable and are not equally spaced.

Comment: If you are able, you should study the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Answer (score 1):

Your $dx$ can be interpreted as a (uniformly distributed) weight on the values of $g(f(x))$ and that's the same case for the $df(x)$. If $f$ is differentiable w.r.t $x$ then you know that a value of $g(f(x))$ "participates" $g(f(x))f'(x)$ to the integral value (for every movement in the variable $x$).

Comment: I didn't understand,could you please explain a bit more easily and elaborately?I didn't get why df(x) behaves in the same way.

Comment: Heuristically speaking: Instead of measuring each $g(x+\bigtriangleup x)$ by $\bigtriangleup x$  (what I mean is that you "add" $g(x+\bigtriangleup x)\bigtriangleup x$ to the integral), you measure  $g(f(x+\bigtriangleup x))$ by the difference $f(x+\bigtriangleup x)-f(x)$. Bringing this $\bigtriangleup x$ to the limit of $0$ yields the result of the weight $f'(x)$ as I mentioned it.